# Too long execution of SELECT SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I need help on the SQL query, how it can be accelerated, I need advice.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
INTO #selectedOrder
FROM [Exchange]. [Dbo]. [BTC_USDT_OpenOrders]
WHERE IsBuy = 0 AND @price> = Price
ORDER BY Price
```

I would be very grateful if someone can help.

This is a table scheme.
[image]
The execution plan

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4dXL.png]

Comment: Please add your table schema to the question, what indexes exist, and also [get the actual execution plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15) and paste it at [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: I suspect you have next to no indexes on your table, and thus it's having the scan the entire thing. Do you also need all the columns? How many columns does your table have?

Comment: If your table has 10M rows and no indexes, searching for the smallest/largest value would have to scan *all* 10M rows to find matches and then order them by price

Comment: You probably want an index `(IsBuy, Price) INCLUDE (...all other columns in select)`

Comment: @squillman i update the post

Comment: Sorry, my Russian is not so strong these days.  Can you translate those images to English?  Just from matching up what I know from the UI, I'd start with @Charlieface 's index suggestion.

Comment: @AlexPIgalyov Please show us the index and primary key definitions.

Comment: @squillman and  i update

Comment: Since `IsBuy` looks like it has low discrimination and the Select clause has `*`, I'd recommend a slightly different index as `(Price, IsBuy)` and no Includes (unless this is a View and the actual columns used in the query are more restricted).

Comment: Please share the query plan as text, you can do this via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Perhaps a filtered index `(Price) INCLUDE (...all other columns in select) WHERE (IsBuy = 0)` At a guess, it also looks like you may have an implicit conversion on `Price`.

Comment: @Charlieface https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sk6SqXsVY

Comment: What percent of rows are `IsBuy = 0`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend one of the following indexes for this query

```
(IsBuy, Price) INCLUDE (OpenOrderId, CreateDate, Price, Amount, Total, CreateUserId)
-- alternatively a filtered index
(Price) INCLUDE (OpenOrderId, CreateDate, Price, Amount, Total, CreateUserId, IsBuy)
  WHERE (IsBuy = 0)
```

This means that the index will already be in order of `Price`, so only a single row needs to be read.